# Angular Xeditable input type url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, x-editable, angular-xeditable

Using Angular Xeditable is it possible to automatically set the data type to URL (so that `<input type="url">` ) within the xeditable?

What's a good way to do this without external libraries using `onbeforesave` if Xeditable doesn't support it?

Comment: Just go through this http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#html5-inputs and you will get the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have to user `editable-url` and then assign it the name of attribute you want to bind it with. That should do what you want.

```
<a href="#" editable-url="user.url">{{ user.url || 'empty' }}</a>
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish173/3ggjn8yv/).

Answer (score 0):

use something like this.....

```
<a href="" data-e-pattern="^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$" data-editable-text="conversion_factor" data-e-required data-e-placeholder="Enter Conversion Factor" data-onaftersave="updateConversionFactor()">{{ conversion_factor || error }}</a>
```

data-e-pattern="**^\d+(.\d{1,2})?$**" - this pattern is for decimal value

find out your URL pattern...